# Passing a variable into d3.js function(d)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Fairly new to d3.js, so there may be something obvious I'm missing. I'm trying to pass a string variable into a function(d) to calculate the "x" position of text labels based on another function. I've got the following (relevant) code:

```
function display_labels(category){
  var categories = vis.selectAll("."+category+"s")
                   .data(cat_data);
  console.log(category); // returns 'year' - correct
  categories.enter().append("text")
                    .attr("class", category+"s")
                    .attr("x", function(d) { 
                      console.log(category); // returns undefined - incorrect
                      // more code after this
```

How can I pass the string into the function so that it will work?

Comment: Strange! hard to believe. do you get errors? On javascript debug do you get category as undefined?

Comment: This should work as expected. I suppose the error is not caused by the code you provided. Are there any other `console.log()`s around? In that case, try to identify the call in your callback by changing it to something like `console.log("x" + category)`.

Comment: @altocumulus I used your suggestion and discovered I'd accidentally created a loop which called the function again with an undefined category, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further below in the code I had an if statement which incorrectly called the same function again with an undefined category. I was using:

```
if (category2 !== 'undefined') { display_labels(category2); }
```

Instead of:

```
if (category2 !== undefined) { display_labels(category2); }
```